# Sort dictionary values alphabetically, where the order of the keys is not important

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have just started learning dictionaries and I have a problem with one task that requires me to sort dictionary values alphabetically.

```
def sort_dictionary(dic: dict) -> dict:
    for i, j in dic.items():
        sorted_dict = {i: sorted(j)}
        print(sorted_dict)
```

So, for example `print(sort_dictionary({"b":["d", "a"], "a":["c", "f"]}))` should give me `{"b":["a", "d"], "a":["c", "f"]}`. My code gives

```
{'b': ['a', 'd']}
{'a': ['c', 'f']}
```

How can this be fixed? Also, if possible, I will ask you not to use lambda, since I have not yet learned it.

Comment: If you want them all in one dict you should put them in one dict. You are creating a separate dict for each key:value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
def sort_dictionary(dic):
    sorted_dict = {}
    for i, j in dic.items():
        sorted_dict[i] = sorted(j)
    return sorted_dict

print(sort_dictionary({"b":["d", "a"], "a":["c", "f"]}))
# {'b': ['a', 'd'], 'a': ['c', 'f']}
```

In your current code, you are making `sorted_dict` with only one key, print it, and then throw it away at each iteration. You need to *accumulate* the "key: sorted list" pair at each iteration, and then return the complete dictionary at the end, *after* you finish the `for` loop.

Also, you need to `return` the dictionary, not `print` the dictionary in the function. The caller `print(sort_dictionary(...))` would obtain the output from the function, and then `print` it. (When you run your own code, you will see the code prints `None`. It is because you didn't write `return` in your code; in this case the function automatically returns `None`.)

Later when you learn about list- and dict-comprehensions, you will find it easier and more readable to write:

```py
def sort_dictionary(dic):
    return {k: sorted(v) for k, v in dic.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do in place sorting in the same dictionary:

```
def sort_dictionary(dic: dict) -> dict:
    for i, j in dic.items():
        j.sort()
    print(dic)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.update()` to update the value:

```
def sort_dictionary(dic: dict) -> dict:
    sorted_dict = dict()
    for i, j in dic.items():
         sorted_dict.update({i: sorted(j)})
    return sorted_dict

print(sort_dictionary({"b":["d", "a"], "a":["c", "f"]}))

# {'b': ['a', 'd'], 'a': ['c', 'f']}
```

Or update while iterating it:

```
def sort_dictionary(dic: dict) -> dict:
    for i, j in dic.items(): 
        dic.update({i: sorted(j)})
    return dic

print(sort_dictionary({"b":["d", "a"], "a":["c", "f"]}))

# {'b': ['a', 'd'], 'a': ['c', 'f']}
```